# Can I Emulate a click, on document ready, with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x9Hfj/) code :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="0" class="hp_nav_label">0</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="1" class="hp_nav_label">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="2" class="hp_nav_label">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="3" class="hp_nav_label">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="4" class="hp_nav_label">4</a>

$('.hp_nav_label').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

When I click on each link, I display its id.

Now, I'd like, on document ready, "handle" automatically the link with `id=2`, without "clicking" on it.

So, having a sort of emulation on that link. Is it possible with jQuery?

Comment: FWIW, although those `id` values are [valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), they're [invalid in previous versions of HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and [invalid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (e.g., if you were going to style the elements using them). HTML4 and earlier, and CSS, require that the first character be an English letter (A-Za-z).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To trigger an event simply call the relevant event function in jQuery on the element, with no handler function defined, like this:

```
$("#2").click();
```

Or there is also `trigger()`, which accepts the event type as a parameter:

```
$("#2").trigger('click');
```

However it's worth noting that `Id` attributes beginning with numbers are invalid, so you will most likely have to change your Ids for them to work properly.

I've updated your fiddle to fix the IDs and show the above code working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/x9Hfj/1/)

Comment: Yeah! It's just an example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trigger`:

```
$('#2').trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `.click()` methods is used also to trigger the `click` event.

```
$('#2').click();
```

This is a shorthand for `$('#2').trigger('click');`.

**Also note that an id cannot start with a digit.**

[jQuery documentation for `click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

[jQuery documentation for `trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you could just call the same function as the click calls.

Did you need something like the $(this) to be populated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) for this:

```
$("#2").triggerHandler("click");
```